# Auxiliary Constructor in Generic Class with Type Bounds Error

Tags: scala, generics, scala-3, f-bounded-polymorphism

Can someone please explain why this code:

```scala
class Whole[T <: Comparable[T]](val name: T):
  val parts: mutable.Map[T, Part[T]] = mutable.LinkedHashMap()

class Part[T <: Comparable[T]](val whole: Whole[T], val name: T):
  //...
  def this(whole: Whole[T], part: Part[T]) =
    this(whole, part.name)
    //...
```

is giving the compiler error below on the line invoking the primary constructor `this(whole, part.name)`?

```
None of the overloaded alternatives of constructor Part in class Part with types
 [T <: Comparable[T]]
  (whole: Whole[T], part: Part[T]): Part[T]
 [T <: Comparable[T]]
  (whole: Whole[T], name: T): Part[T]
match arguments ((whole : Whole[T]), (part.name : T))
    this(whole, part.name)
```

How would I make this work?

I'm using Scala 3.2.1.

Everything is fine if I remove the type bounds...

Comment: It's interesting that if we replace the auxiliary constructor with a factory method then there is no error https://scastie.scala-lang.org/A3dKGU4YQs6vdmqtcd27tg Looks like a bug. In 2.13 there is no error https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Eq9h5GwoTWy3e7njR59OdQ

Comment: Scala 3 bugs should be reported at https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues

Comment: Thanks, @dmytro-mitin. I opened issue [#16852](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/16852) and switched to a factory method for now.